# Can an analyzer validate that namespaces properly match the file location

Tags: c#, roslyn

It is conventional to name namespaces in a C# solution such that they match the default namespace for the project plus the name of any sub-directories for the containing file.

For example, a file called `Haddock.cs` is in a directory called `Fish` and the default namespace (in the first tab of the project's properties in VS) is `Lakes` then the file should contain something like

```
namespace Lakes.Fish
{
    public class Haddock
    {
    }
}
```

The [StyleCop analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) project contains a nice rule that validates that the class name matches the file name.

Is there any way I can write a rule that verifies that the namespace name is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the file path from a `SyntaxTreeAction` using the `Tree.FilePath` off of the `SyntaxTreeContext`.

Once you have the path, you can then parse that and compare it with the name of all of the Names of the `NamesSpaceDeclarationSyntax` nodes in the tree.

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a way to get at the default namespace for a project at this time.

Here is a quick sample I threw together that does what it can so far.  The processing/comparing of the path to the namespace is rudimentary and there is probably a better way to do it, but this should get you started.

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterCompilationStartAction((compilationSyntax) =>
    {
        compilationSyntax.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction((syntaxTreeContext) =>
        {
            var semModel = compilationSyntax.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTreeContext.Tree);
            var filePath = syntaxTreeContext.Tree.FilePath;

            if (filePath == null)
                return;

            var namespaceNodes = syntaxTreeContext.Tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();
            var parentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

            // This will only work on windows and is not very robust.
            var parentDirectoryWithDots = parentDirectory.Replace("\\", ".").ToLower();

            foreach (var ns in namespaceNodes)
            {
                var symbolInfo = semModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(ns) as INamespaceSymbol;
                var name = symbolInfo.ToDisplayString();

                if (!parentDirectoryWithDots.EndsWith(name.ToLower().Trim()))
                {
                    syntaxTreeContext.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(
                       Rule, ns.Name.GetLocation(), parentDirectoryWithDots));
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That won't check nested `namespace` declarations.

Comment: @SLaks Nice catch, fixed.

Comment: That's still wrong; `ns.Name` won't include outer blocks.

Comment: @SLaks I updated it to get the DisplayString from the SemanticModel, so I think this should handle that case now.

Comment: Thanks! This is of limited usefulness without a way to get the default namespace, so I added this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5252. Let's hope it goes somewhere!